# Big O Hierarchy log log 16 less than 1

Tags: logarithms

My lecture has given me a Big O hierarchy table that shows $1 \leq \log(\log(16))$.

How is this possible given $\log(\log(16)) = 0.08066976367$?

More specifically, $1 \leq log(log(n))$ for all $n\geq16$

---

Edit: adding this table to clarify my source
[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Are you using $\log=\log_2, \log=log_{10}$ or $log=log_e$?

Comment: My source is the Big O Hierarchy

Comment: Probably means natural logarithm, since $\ln\ln 16 = 1.019781440538226$ and $\log_2 \log_2 n\geq1$ for $n\geq 4.$

Comment: Thanks Thomas, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using $\log = \log_2$, so $\log_2 16 = 4$ and $\log \log 16 = 2$...

Comment: Thanks, understood.

Answer (score 0):

Found another issue.   I was using [desmos.com](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5mhefjr5dp) and inputting my expressions incorrectly.   x^3logx is not the same as x3 * ln(x)